# Proper static usage with BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, border-layout, code-documentation

Documentation I have read for BorderLayout claim that is is best to use `PAGE_END`, `PAGE_START`, `LINE_START`, `LINE_END`, and `CENTER`. (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)

However, I have also found documentation that uses `NORTH`, `EAST`, `SOUTH`, `WEST`, and `CENTER`. (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) since the first set map directly to this one.

Which set of constants should be used when using `BorderLayout`, and if it doesn't matter then which set would be most commonly used?

Comment: Could someone please explain why this is opinion based? is it because both are perfectly valid?

Comment: You're correct, it's not opinion based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not equivalent

The documentation for [`LINE_END`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/BorderLayout.html#LINE_END) for example states:

> For Western, left-to-right and top-to-bottom orientations, this is equivalent to EAST

That is, in other orientations (e.g., Hebrew) it's not equivalent to `EAST`.